# Backup data from desktop to laptop connected through Netgear router

Tags: backup, networking

I wanted to backup my data from a desktop computer onto a laptop, where both are connected through a Netgear router, the laptop wirelessly and the desktop PC wired.

What all are the basics of backing up the whole data. Please share some good website links, where I could read the basic and efficient techniques to back up data.

Comment: You'll need to let people know what OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

[Crashplan](http://crashplan.com) is excellent.  It allows you to back up your files to another one of your computers, to an external hard drive, to Crashplan central ($3.50 a month), or a friends computer.  This is a very full featured backup software.  The only disadvantages of it are that the free version is ad-supported.  You can also sync files across computers using [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/).  You install the Dropbox software on each computer you want to sync the data with, put the files that you want to sync in your "Dropbox", a folder created by the program during installation.  The files in your Dropbox are uploaded to the Dropbox server, and then downloaded to all your other computers running Dropbox.  The disadvantage of Dropbox is that you are only allowed 2GB of space.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of backup tools out there some of which are cross platform. This one should do what you need http://www6.crashplan.com/landing/index.html it supports automatic backups whenever your connected.  For added security it allows backup to web based storage or a friends pc over the internet.